# Encrypting using C# AES encryption & decryption from these PHP codes

Tags: c#, php, encryption, aes, rijndael

I am facing some issues in AES encryption using PHP and decode the same using C #. My reference [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx).

Here is the PHP code:

```
function encrypt_string($input, $key)
   {
       $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
       return preg_replace('/=/', "", base64_encode($iv . mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, hash("sha256", $key, true), $input, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)));
   }

function decrypt_string($input, $key)
   {
       $input .= "=";
       $data = base64_decode($input);
       $iv = substr($data, 0, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));
       return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,hash('sha256', $key, true),substr($data, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)),MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv),"\0");
   }
```

Here is C# code that I tried:

```
private static byte[] sha256_data(string input)
{
    SHA256 hash = SHA256Managed.Create();
    Encoding encode = Encoding.UTF8;
    return hash.ComputeHash(encode.GetBytes(input));
}

private string encode_data(string data, string key)
{
    byte[] buff;

    RijndaelManaged rij = new RijndaelManaged();

    rij.BlockSize = 256;
    rij.KeySize = 256;

    rij.GenerateIV();
    rij.Key = sha256_data(key);

    rij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform encoder = rij.CreateEncryptor(rij.Key, rij.IV);
    using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream crypt = new CryptoStream(mem, encoder, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] temp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            crypt.Write(temp, 0, temp.Length);

        }
        buff = mem.ToArray();
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
} 

private string decode_data(string input, string key)
{
    RijndaelManaged rij = new RijndaelManaged();

    rij.KeySize = 256;
    rij.BlockSize = 256;

    rij.Key = sha256_data(key);
    rij.GenerateIV();

    rij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    rij.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    ICryptoTransform decrypter = rij.CreateDecryptor();

    byte[] buff;
    using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cstream = new CryptoStream(mem, decrypter, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
            cstream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        buff = mem.ToArray();
    }
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff);
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

when you decode you must parse the IV that was used for encoding not generate a new one.

Comment: A bit of code would have helped me with this answer. In the end though, I made more progress with code found here - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13714/symmetric-encryption-decryption-routine-using-aes